# Oracle DB not declared 'RIGHT'

Tags: oracle

i expected get `ls_fr`, `ls_to` which is update using if statement.

But the query exception message says `Not declared RIGHT`. I thought `RIGHT` is built-in function. How can i solve this or declare `RIGHT` function?

```
declare
ls_today VARCHAR2(15);
ls_time VARCHAR2(15);
ls_bef_day VARCHAR2(15);
ls_next_day VARCHAR2(15);
ls_fr VARCHAR2(15);
ls_to VARCHAR2(15);
begin
ls_today := '20181105';
ls_time := '20181105175612';
ls_bef_day := '20181104';
ls_next_day := '20181106';
If RIGHT(ls_time, 6) >= '000000' and RIGHT(ls_time, 6) <= '055959' Then 
ls_fr := ls_bef_day;
ls_to := ls_today;
Else
ls_fr := ls_today;
ls_to := ls_next_day;
End If;
select ls_fr, ls_to INTO ls_fr, ls_to FROM DUAL;
end;
```

Comment: Where [in the Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Single-Row-Functions.html#GUID-06062705-1EC8-44ED-89B8-0F0573B74EA2) did you find the function `right()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name umm... sorry im noob.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simpliest would be tho use `SUBSTR` instead of `RIGHT` with negative position (as there is no `RIGHT` in oracle) :

```
If SUBSTR(ls_time, -6) >= '000000' and SUBSTR(ls_time, -6) <= '055959' Then
```

Negative position with `SUBSTR` means the position is given according to the end of the string. And if you omit the length parameter as above the substring is taken till the end of the string. Therefore `SUBSTR(..., -pos)` is equivalent to `RIGHT(..., pos)`.